# how to putExtra and intent class together with one intent

Tags: android, android-intent

i want use one intent that intent class with put extra

```
 case R.id.button_6:
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, class_);
        this.startActivity(intent);

        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), class_.class);
        i.putExtra("data",data);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

Comment: I didn't understand anything!

Comment: how to above code use one intent that intent class with put extra @ hegazy

Comment: why do you have two startActivity() calls?

Comment: i use a list view in class_ that fill by data when not use  startActivity(i); not show data @ hegazy

Answer (score 1):

You don't need all that stuff, just:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), class_.class);
i.putExtra("data", data);
startActivity(i);
```

You create the intent with `class_` and pass `data` as an extra.

Comment: when use it app give me exception :java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Class.getName()' on a null object reference

Comment: What is class_, where is it set?

Comment: Replace `class_`by its class name. I mean, if `class_` is `MyActivity`, pass this to intent: `MyActivity.class`

Comment: Update your answer with your current code and add the exception stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Class.getName()' on a null object reference

```
public class class_ extends Activity  {

                ListAdapter adapter=null;
                ListView lst;
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data= new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();;

                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.class_);
                  lst=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

                      Intent i = getIntent();



                        data= (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) i.getSerializableExtra("data");
                        if(data!=null){

                        adapter = new list_view(this, data);

                      lst.setAdapter(adapter);
                        }
                        }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Intent i = new Intent(this,class_.class);
  i.putExtra("data",data);
  startActivity(i);
```

And get it in another activity like this..

```
  String data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("data");
```

It is for string you can define type which you are sending from your activity